Find the $\int_C \frac{e^{-2z^2}}{(z-2i)(z-5)} dz$
I am trying to find
$$\int_C \frac{e^{-2z^2}}{(z-2i)(z-5)}\,dz $$
where $C$ is the circle of radius three about the origin and I am not sure if my approach is correct.
I noticed that out of the singularities $z=2i$ and $z=5,$ $z=2i$ lies within the circle. Therefore I defined $f(z) =  \frac{e^{-2z^2}}{(z-5)}$ and rewrote the integral as $\int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-2i)}\,dz.$ Then I can apply the Cauchy Integral Formula which tells us that $\int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-2i)}\,dz  = (2 \pi i) f(2i) = (2 \pi i) \frac{e^8}{(2i-5)}$
Is this the correct approach? Thanks in advance!

Don't re-write the integral, since only one of the poles lies in the region, you only need to compute the residue of that pole. The answer will be $2\pi i$ times the residue.

Using Cauchys integral formula its:
$$2\pi i \bigg(\frac{e^{-2z^2}}{z-5}\bigg\vert_{z=2i}\bigg).$$
As the residue is zero for $z=5$, youre above answer is correct!
Hope you can finish from here!!
You should get
$$2\pi i \bigg(\frac{e^8}{2i-5}\bigg).$$

By Cauchy's Integral formula,
$$
\int_C \frac{e^{-2 z^2}}{(z-2 i)(z-5)} d z= 2\pi i\left( \lim_{z\to 2i}  \frac{e^{-2 z^2}}{(z-5)}\right)=2\pi i\left(\frac{e^{-2(2i)^2}}{2i -5}\right)
=\frac{2\pi ie^8}{2i-5}.$$

I commented the solution before you submitted then started immediately typing it up. I believe you posted while i was writing. But OP, please give the accept to the other user :))

Aw thanks :) appreciate that

@homosapien There is no competition we’re all just here to get our fix of complex analysis :))

Agreed! I took and passed my complex qualifier not too long ago so this was fresh in my memory! Are you a complex analyst?

@homosapien I'm studying probability I but I enjoy complex it’s such a neat course and I struggled at it in undergrad. Now I love it and find the proofs so aesthetic whereas in undergrad I couldn’t figure many of the clever tricks out myself. Congrats on finishing your quals!

Oh wow yes complex is a beautiful field with lots of beautiful results and proofs! Also, I still have one more left I passed top and complex have real variable or measure theory left this may wish me luck!!

Good luck! Measure theory is so much less aesthetic I still have nightmares from the vitali set construction. But I thought L^p spaces were cool and I liked the Riesz-Markov theorem and Radon Nikodym. Hopefully you don’t have to memorize the awful Caratheodory extension theorem. Also got such a kick out of functional analysis purely just because it’s like oh what that’s that thing from linalg but infinite dimensional!

Yeah its just on basic measure theory, integration, differentiation, Lp spaces, Hilbert and Banach spaces, weak derivatives and Sobolev spaces. To date my favorite proof is the Lp Lq containments iff your space is infinite and contains sets of arb small or large positive measure. and agreed its much less aesthetic than complex. So like apps of MCT, DCT, MCT for sets and so on.. Holders inequality Minkowskis inequality..

Thank god the Vitali set or existence of non (Lebesgue) measurable sets wont be on the exam..I had to prove this existence for my masters qual in measure theory.

Ah good times. I am currently taking a course in smooth manifolds following Lee and am loving not having to do analysis. I think I might have taken measure theory 4 times through all the prob and analysis courses I took. I basically have a degree in the definition of outer measure… yikes

Oh nice I took a course last sem following Lees intro to smooth mani.
